# cut log files with sed and variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, sed

I have log files with dates and events. I want check this file from time to time and see only records from a particular point in time on, e.g., last error during last check.

```
05/03/2016 23:55:25.142639 user1
05/04/2016 12:55:25.142639 user4
05/04/2016 13:57:25.142639 user3
05/04/2016 13:51:02.236522 user2
```

I want to have the date in a variable

```
variable="05/04/2016 12:55:25.142639"
```

I tried to run the following command, but without success:

```
[sdtest tmp]$ sed -n "/$variable/,\$p" logfile.out
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `0'
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because your command expands to

```
sed -n /05/04/2016 12:55:25.142639/,$p logfile.out
```

Do you see the problem? Too many forward slashes confuse sed, it tries to execute the command `0` at the address `/05/`.

To fix that, you have to use a different address delimiter. Unlike for `s///`, where you can just use a different delimiter as in `s|||`, for an address you have to escape the first one, for example:

```
$ sed -n "\|$variable|,\$p" logfile.out
05/04/2016 12:55:25.142639 user4
05/04/2016 13:57:25.142639 user3
05/04/2016 13:51:02.236522 user2
```

Quote from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses):

> `\%regexp%`
>
> (The `%` may be replaced by any other single character.)
>
> This also matches the regular expression *regexp*, but allows one to
>   use a different delimiter than `/`. This is particularly useful if the
>   *regexp* itself contains a lot of slashes, since it avoids the tedious escaping of every `/`. If *regexp* itself includes any delimiter
>   characters, each must be escaped by a backslash (`\`).

---

<sub>Remark: to avoid the escaping issues caused by using double quote, we could also have double quotes only around the shell variable and single quotes around the rest:</sub>

```
sed -n '\|'"$variable"'|,$p' logfile.out
```

Comment: is it possible to remove pattern from result (what was in variable)? And see only the rest of test

Comment: @mario Yes, but remember that the variable matches only on one line, and then you say "from here to the end of the file", so you can't just remove your variable, as that would affect only one line. In general, to remove something, you substitute it with the empty string: `s/pattern//`. In your case, you want a pattern for everything up to and including the second blank in the line: `s/^\([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]\)\{2\}//`, and you want to combine it with your address range: `sed -n '\|'"$variable"'|,$s/^\([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]\)\{2\}//p' logfile.out` where `p` is a flag of the `s` command.